# How to check if element in groovy array/hash/collection/list?

Tags: arrays, list, groovy

How do I figure out if an array contains an element? 
I thought there might be something like `[1, 2, 3].includes(1)` which would evaluate as `true`.

Comment: Can you find the index out also of where this equal element is in the list?

Comment: @AtharvaJohri `assert [12,42,33].indexOf(42) == 1`

Answer (score 159, accepted):

.contains() is the best method for lists, but for maps you will need to use .containsKey() or .containsValue()

```
[a:1,b:2,c:3].containsValue(3)
[a:1,b:2,c:3].containsKey('a')
```

Comment: And, in addition, to check if a map contains some not null value under a certain key, it is enough to check the following expression `if(aMap["aKey"]==aValue)`.

Answer (score 285):

Some syntax sugar

```
1 in [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Careful. `def m = [a: true]; 'a' in m` → true yet `def m = [a: false]; 'a' in m` → false!

Comment: How do you negate this?

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge `!(1 in [1,2,3])`

Comment: The way to deal with `[a:false]` is to use contains. `[a: false].containsKey('a')` -> true

Comment: @Big McLargeHuge negation is also possible like this: `1 !in [1,2,3]` ([Membership operator Groovy](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_membership_operator))

Comment: Beautiful! Despite the caveat with booleans @JesseGlick mentions. (Where when `a` is `false`, this might even be the desired result, depending on what the question is.)

Answer (score 70):

For lists, use `contains`:

```
[1,2,3].contains(1) == true
```

Comment: Probably you wanted to say [1,2,3].contains(1).  Because I am guessing contains function itself already returns a boolean. Why do you want to again compare it with a hardcoded 'true'.

Comment: @HarshayBuradkar To make really sure `true == true`, of course #joke

Answer (score 10):

You can use Membership operator:

```
def list = ['Grace','Rob','Emmy']
assert ('Emmy' in list)
```

[Membership operator Groovy](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_membership_operator)

Answer (score 8):

If you really want your includes method on an ArrayList, just add it:

```
ArrayList.metaClass.includes = { i -> i in delegate }
```

Answer (score 3):

IMPORTANT Gotcha for using .contains() on a Collection of Objects, such as Domains.  If the Domain declaration contains a EqualsAndHashCode, or some other equals() implementation to determine if those Ojbects are equal, and you've set it like this...

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = "settingNameId, value")
```

then the .contains(myObjectToCompareTo) will evaluate the data in myObjectToCompareTo with the data for each Object instance in the Collection. So, if your equals method isn't up to snuff, as mine was not, you might see unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

```
def fruitBag = ["orange","banana","coconut"]
def fruit = fruitBag.collect{item -> item.contains('n')}
```

I did it like this so it works if someone is looking for it.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use matches with regular expression like this:

```
boolean bool = List.matches("(?i).*SOME STRING HERE.*")
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? AFAIK there is no 'matches' method on list:
'groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.matches()'